# Profiling python-tensorflow-1.14

Tags: tensorflow, profiling

I'm profiling my tensorflow training and found out that some operations were performed on the CPU instead of the GPU.

When forcing the device with `with graph.device("/gpu:0")`, a slicing operation raised an error saying

> Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.

I "solved" it by forcing the device with `with graph.device("/device:XLA_GPU:0")` for the specific slicing operation. However, when profiling the process, I get (too) many transfers (`MemcpyHtoD` and `MemcpyDtoH`). In addition, even all the nodes of the graph are assigned to the `GPU` (or the `XLA_GPU` for the slicing operation), it appears that some variables sit on the `CPU`(see the `Adam/VariableV2` on the image below, happening just after a `MemcpyHtoD` and followed by a `MemcpyDtoH`)!

[image]

I have trouble investigating and understanding how tensorflow handles the data, the operations and the device they are executed on.

- Why isn't tensorflow able to run some very basic operations (like slicing) on the GPU?
- Why are the transfers required between the host and the device for the `Adam/VariableV2`?
- Are data transfer required between `GPU` and `XLA_GPU`?